If a class doesn't overload the == operator, then what is the value of an object of that class?
From the Python reference:

Every object has an identity, a type and a value.


Comparison operators implement a particular notion of what the value of an object is. One can think of them as defining the value of an object indirectly, by means of their comparison implementation.

And Luciano Ramalho in his book "Fluent Python" says that (on p.206 of the second ed.):

The operator == compares the values of objects (the data they hold), while is compares their identities.

So, one of the possible definitions of the object's value (I think this is the only definition of the object's value that is at least somehow, very carefully and without details, mentioned in the official reference) is the following. The value of an object is the data that is used by the __eq__() method  of that object. But there are classes that don't override this method. What is the value of an instance of such a class?
(Please note that I am not asking for a rigorous and strict definition here because it is unlikely to exist. I just need something a bit more practically useful than "object's value is the information that this object represents" – this is the phrase that people say when I ask them about the concept of an object's value, it is a true phrase but not very useful because it is too abstract.)

For example, let's say we have some function f - an instance of the built-in function class. This class doesn't override __eq__(), so in this case the == operator just compares the identities of its operands (if both operands are functions). But I don't think that we can say that the value of the object f is the same as the identity of f. Indeed, people say that user-defined functions are mutable objects, in other words, it is possible to change their value. But it is not possible to change the identity of f (or any other object). So, the value of f is not equal to id(f). It should be defined differently and I hope it can be defined properly (if not in Python in general then at least in CPython).
Here on stackoverflow I have seen some definitions of a function object value, for example here:

It's "value" is a set of other values, which are sufficient to define exact same function.

But I am not sure that this is a "canonical" definition.

"By default, object implements __eq__() by using is": https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.eq

object implements __eq__() by using is and thus is the default behavior

@Carcigenicate I know this fact. So, what is the value of an object instance, for example?

This might be relevant : Compare object instances for equality by their attributes

"value of the object" doesn't really make sense. An object is a value. f itself is a name we use to refer to the value, so it's absolutely true that  f and id(f) are different: one is a name that refers to a function, the other is an expression that evaluates to an int value that represents the function.

The "value" of is is the memory address

@chepner Let's say we have a mutable object a = [1, 2, 3]. We can change a value of this object by a.append(3). But the object will stay the same (its id). So, why you say "object is a value"?

you've highlighted the wrong part of the sentence "Comparison operators implement a particular notion of what the value of an object is". using the address to compare two objects is perfectly fine and has nothing to do with its value. "One can think of them as" hints that the following is probably not a formal definition

@folengateis Of course, this is just one of the ways to define the value. In my question I didn't ask for rigorous and strict definition (Python didn't have formal definitions for many important concepts). I just need some "reasonable" and "practical" definition.

@Rodvi You're describing the state of the object. There's no need to overload the term "value" to distinguish between the object itself and the state the object is in.

It's just a matter of wording.

The operator == compares the values of objects (the data they hold), while is compares their identities.

Of course, I could define a class as follows:
def MyClass:
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.x == 3

Now, of course, that's not comparing values. MyClass isn't even holding any interesting sort of value! And the right hand side is ignored!
If you want to take the approach to definitions you're taking, then it would be more correct to say "The operator == invokes the __eq__ method on the left operand, passing both operands, and returns its result". There, now there's no discussion of values, hence no ambiguity as to what a "value" is.
But if you want to take the approach of Python as one would actually want to use it, then == compares values, and the "value" of an object is determined by whatever __eq__ and related methods treat it as being. By default, for objects of class types, that's id().

Ok, then what is the meaning of the phrase "function object is a mutable object"? I thought "mutable object" in Python means that "we can change the value of such object" (excluding container types - they have different definition of mutability). But __eq__ only uses the id of the function and this id never changes.

@Rodvi Where did you get "function object is a mutable object" from?

@khelwood here and in many other places

As with the definition of "value", "mutable" is defined in a practical rather than mathematical way. A function can be modified; you can do def foo(): pass, then foo.bar = 3, and then print(foo.bar).

@Sneftel So can we say that this code (foo.bar) will change the function value? This code definitely will not change the function's id.

@Rodvi You can say that if you like. You could also say that it doesn't. We don't usually talk about a function's "value", so it doesn't really matter. And if you did want to talk about it, it would be a good idea to describe what you meant by "value" in that instance.

(And, of course, since we really don't usually do foo.bar with foo a function, it would be a good idea to describe what you're up to even if you're not trying to define "value").

I just finished writing a class that uses a small subset of its instance data to define __eq__. In this case, the attributes I use are defined in __init__ and that tuple of attributes is then referred to in __eq__:
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Mycls):
        return all(self.__dict__[a]==getattr(other, a) for a in self.attribs)
    return NotImplemented     

So short answer: It Depends on whatever equality of the objects means To You.
